# Flashbots error unable to decode txn

Tags: ethers.js, flashbots

I just tried to use flashbots in combination with ethers and my smart contract. For my implementation i used the [ethers-provider-flashbots-bundle](https://github.com/flashbots/ethers-provider-flashbots-bundle) guide from github. I did everything exactly like described but everytime my simulation gets an error response:

> status: 400,
>
> reason: 'bad request',
>
> body: '{"error":"unable to decode txs"}',

Here is my relevant code:

```
    const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('goerli');
    const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic("[mnemonic]");  
    const myContract = new ethers.Contract("[contract address]", myABI, provider);

    const flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(
        provider,
        wallet,
        'https://relay-goerli.flashbots.net/',
        'goerli'
    );

    const txn = await myContract.populateTransaction.simpleSwap(ethers.utils.parseEther(0.001), 0, path, {
        gasPrice: ethers.utils.formatUnits(await connection.getGasPrice(), "wei"),
        gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(600000),
        nonce: connection.getTransactionCount(wallet.address)
    });

    const txBundle = [
        {
          signer: wallet,
          transaction: txn
        }
    ];
    
   const signedTransactions = await flashbotsProvider.signBundle(txBundle);
   const targetBlockNumber = (await connection.getBlockNumber()) + 1;
   const simulation = await flashbotsProvider.simulate(signedTransactions, targetBlockNumber);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(simulation, null, 2));
```

Here again the whole response I get, no matter what I try:

```
{
reason: 'bad response',
code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
status: 400,
headers: {
date: 'Tue, 21 Feb 2023 18:06:49 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '32',
connection: 'close',
'x-amzn-requestid': '4796dc12-3844-499d-8d02-8fa216abfdbf',
'x-amz-apigw-id': 'As45CHpdCYcFd1w=',
vary: 'Origin',
'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-63f50839-69ab4464245af2172e0bbef9;Sampled=0'
},
body: '{"error":"unable to decode txs"}',
requestBody: '{"method":"eth_callBundle","params":[{"txs":["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"],"blockNumber":"0x822fe8","stateBlockNumber":"latest"}],"id":42,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
requestMethod: 'POST',
url: 'https://relay-goerli.flashbots.net/'
}
```

I hope someone can help me. I would really appreciate it. If you have more questions to my code, please ask.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem just now.

The solution was to add the `chainId` in each `TransactionRequest` object of your **bundleTransactions**.

The github example doesn't include the chain id in each `TransactionRequest` object of the bundleTransactions array passed to the `FlashbotsBundleProvider` object's `signBundle` or `sendBundle` method.

**Modified github example code where the error appeared to be:**

```
const bundleTransactions: Array<FlashbotsBundleTransaction | FlashbotsBundleRawTransaction> = [
    {
      transaction: {
        //chain id was not included in the github example, but it's required
        //chainId: 5,//assuming you're testing on ethereum's goerli testnet
        to: walletExecutor.address,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
        value: gasEstimateTotal.mul(gasPrice),
        gasLimit: 21000,
      },
      signer: walletSponsor
    },
    ...sponsoredTransactions.map((transaction, txNumber) => {
      return {
        transaction: {
          //chain id was not included in the github example, but it's required
          //chainId: 5,//assuming you're testing on ethereum's goerli testnet
          ...transaction,
          gasPrice: gasPrice,
          gasLimit: gasEstimates[txNumber],
        },
        signer: walletExecutor,
      }
    })
  ]
```

I also encountered another error at the `FlashbotsBundleProvider` creation method call.

https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/advanced/goerli-testnet

The link above helped out. I needed to pass the network's name also to the `create` method along with the `connectionInfoOrUrl` passed in the example.

**The code in the example for goerli testnet:**

```
const flashbotsProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(
    provider, walletRelay, 'https://relay-goerli.epheph.com/'
);
```

**The code that actually works:**

```
const flashbotsProvider = await flashbots.FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(
  provider,
  authSigner,//---same as walletRelay in the example. Just a different name.
  "https://relay-goerli.flashbots.net",
  "goerli"//the netowork name missing
);
```

I'm currently testing an helper class I built from the flasbots api.

It should be a simple Flashbots builder class useful for executing any type of flashbots bundle transaction.

I will edit this to include an npm link once I'm done.

**Here is how one will use the Flashbots builder class:**

```
//Build a flasbot
FlashBot.Builder()
.addSponsorPrivateKey(process.env.SPONSOR_PK_ETH)
.addExecutorPrivateKey(process.env.EXECUTOR_PK_ETH)
.addBlockChainRpcProvider(BLOCKCHAIN_RPC_PROVIDER_TEST)
.addBundleProviderConnectionInfoOrUrl(FLASH_BOTS_RPC_URL_TEST)
.addBundleProviderNetwork(FLASH_BOTS_RPC_NETWORK_TEST)
.addBlockchainNetworkId(FLASH_BOTS_RPC_NETWORK_ID_TEST)
.build()
.then(async (flashBot) => {
    //access the sponsor and executor Wallet object
    const sponsor = flashBot.getSponsorWallet()
    const executor = flashBot.getExecutorWallet()

    console.log(`sponsor: ${sponsor.address} | executor: ${executor.address}`)
    
    //create an ERC20 transfer
    const engine = new TransferERC20(
        flashBot.getProvider(), 
        executor.address, 
        sponsor.address, 
        TOKEN_ADDRESS_TEST,
        utils.parseEther("500000")
    );
    //get the transaction
    const sponsoredTransactions = await engine.getSponsoredTransactions()

    console.log("Engine Description:", await engine.description(), sponsoredTransactions)
    
    flashBot
    .addMultipleBundleTx(sponsoredTransactions)
    .execute(authSignerPrivateKey)//If the authSigner is not passed, one will be generated and included in the promise's result
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("result:", result)
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log("error:", e.message)
    })
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log("error:", e.message)
})
```

**Edit:**

The flasbots builder library is now avilable on npm. Install with:
npm install flashbots-builder

**Library Github Repo:**
https://github.com/feyi-tech/flashbots-builder

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try this in the next few days and document my experience for others, that have this problem!

Comment: Alright Steve! Please let us know. Thanks!